# Disable user login from multiple devices at the sametime, in Ejabberd/XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, smack

> **Environment:**
>
> Ejabberd Version : 16.04
>
> Smack-android-4.1.0

I'm working on an Android chat application. Currently, same user credentials can be used login from multiple devices.

The current scenario is as follows:

```
1. User logs in into the app in device A
2. Using the same username and password, the user logs successfully into the app in device B
3. Now device A says, it is disconnected, but continue the chat in device B
```

However, according to the given requirement, it should behave like this:

```
1. User logs in into the app in device A
2. Using the same username and password, when the user tries to log in from device B, it should not allow it. 
(Since he is already logged in from device A)
```

Would be glad to hear your solutions/ideas on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to resolve the problem using the option **resource_conflict**

According to [Ejabberd Configuring Docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/)

> The option **resource_conflict** defines the action when a client attempts
> to login to an account with a resource that is already connected. The
> option syntax is:
>
> **resource_conflict: setresource|closenew|closeold:** The possible values
> match exactly the three possibilities described in XMPP Core: section
> 7.7.2.2. The default value is closeold. If the client uses old Jabber Non-SASL authentication (XEP-0078), then this option is not respected,
> and the action performed is closeold.

So open `ejabberd.yml`  and add the following line to that file.

```
resource_conflict: closenew
```

Then restart the ejabberd server.

Now it will disallow the resource binding attempt of the newly connecting client and maintain the session of the currently connected client.

References:

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-7.7.2.2
2. Read @rubycon's answer on this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860779/5361779

Answer (score 1):

From XMPP spec:

"If there is already an active resource of the same name, the server MUST either (1) terminate the active resource and allow the newly-requested session, or (2) disallow the newly-requested session and maintain the active resource. Which of these the server does is up to the implementation, although it is RECOMMENDED to implement case #1."

More info here https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#session

So your current scenario is a recommended one.

However, I have quickly checked for ejabberd src code and found it can be configured somehow (closeold -> closenew)

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L964

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L873

I'm not an Erlang specialist, but looks like it can be achieved by modifying the source code

Comment: Thank you @Rubycon your answer helped me to find an approach to resolve this problem.

Comment: @B378 great to hear it! You can mark this answer as correct then

Comment: Thanks, @Rubycon. However, it was resolved by updating the yml file as given in Ejabberd Configuring Docs, **not the source code**. Since it's different from this, I added the followed procedure as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If device B sets as resource one different than device A, both can be connected to the same account correctly. In your tests, device B sets the exact same resource than device A, and then ejabberd kicks the older session.

I see there's an option to limit the number of sessions an account can have active in the server. The problem is that it kicks the older session, but you would like to disallow the new login. See
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#limiting-opened-sessions-with-acl

Comment: I referred the given link and made the changes to the yml as given. However, it will not disallow the new login. It will enable the new login attempt and disable the previously logged-in session.

Comment: This is right. From XMPP spec:

If there is already an active resource of the same name, the server MUST either (1) terminate the active resource and allow the newly-requested session, or (2) disallow the newly-requested session and maintain the active resource. Which of these the server does is up to the implementation, although it is RECOMMENDED to implement case #1.

More info here https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#session

Comment: So, above current scenario is RECOMMENDED scenario. I think you need to check for Ejabberd is it possible to switch to case #2.